# Cloud Data Loss Prevention - global vs local settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform, data-loss

Three questions about Google's [Data Loss Prevention](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/concepts-infotypes#example_1) API:

1. There are [global types and local types](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/infotypes-reference). What happens if I use the global types? Does it use a combination of all local types?
2. When one should use local types, and when global types?
3. Where can I find an example of config file for using local types?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [the REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/InspectConfig). The inspect job config need a list of types. You simply have to provide the list of infotype that you want to find.

This list of infotypes is a list of built in infotype with common PII that you can find. Some are generic (global) others are specific to a country (special format). You can also create [your custom info type](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-custom-infotypes) to detect non standard/ non built in info type.

Comment: I followed your recommendation but still, I cannot get the API to recognize any local type. Could that be because these are high-sensitivity types, that are pre-GA and only available to selected users? See here: https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/high-sensitivity-infotypes-reference

Comment: DLP use Info type to check if the data match a pattern. It's not 100% safe, and you can have some missing row, or false positive. If nothing is detected, you can write your custom info type, or make sure that you data match the built in infotype. Last option is to contact Google, because it's in preview and some issues can exist.